# Android create a service application

Tags: android

My scenario is: I have two applications Main and WSCaller.

- Main is an app which call to WSCaller to do some WS call and wait for result.
- WSCaller is an app which do not need any activity, screen, or launcher icon. It just like a service application which runin background and return data to Main app.

Can I create such a WSCaller app?

I tried to create a simple one as following.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ch.tpg.syscontrolws.mobile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".activities.ServiceStarter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="mypackage.CALL_WS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ServiceStarter.java

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("ServiceStarter", intent.getAction());
        // Do not know yet how to return data to Main?
    }
}
```

In Main, I did:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("mypackage.CALL_WS");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But the WSCaller does not started and receive message.

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Android apps require an Activity to start. So you need to have somekind of placeholder UI. Also you need to declare the service in the manifest.

Like this:

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
     android:exported=["true" | "false"]
     android:icon="drawable resource"
     android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
     android:label="string resource"
     android:name="string"
     android:permission="string"
     android:process="string" >
. . .
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: So, could you please add some code to show how the WSCaller return data back to Main? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the OnBind function in the Service class. see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. You can use the binder to communicate to the Activity that bound the Service.

Comment: Thank you, Rockernaap, this is what I looking for: remove all activity configuration in manifest file, keep only service.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that, it is a separate application.And that's why it follows its own configuration.

On Android 3.1 and higher, the user must launch one of your activities before any manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver will work.
 Alternate way to start it is.

```
private void  launchComponent(String packageName, String name)
{
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
    launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startService(launch_intent);
}

public void startApplication(String application_name)
{
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
     //   intent.setAction(Intent.)

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfo_list = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info:resolveinfo_list)
        {
            if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(application_name))
            {
                launchComponent(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                break;
            }
            else{

        }
        }
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "There was a problem loading the application: "+application_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For launcher app require Activity. You can make your activity transparent. You cannot create service as a app. Yes, but one thing you can do

You can make another process from your activity and in another process you can start service.

For create service in a seperate process you need to add `:process` attribute in manifest.xml.

so that's how you can call your service in different process and different process will not share non static and static dynamic memory.